# Get an ordered dictionary from an ordinary one

Tags: python, dictionary

What is a good way to get an ordered dictionary from a regular dictionary? I need the keys (and these keys are known ahead of time) to be in a certain order. I will be "dump"ing a list of these dictionaries into a JSON file and need things ordered a certain way.

--- Edited and added the following

For instance i have a dictionary  ...

```
employee = { 'phone': '1234567890', 'department': 'HR', 'country': 'us', 'name': 'Smith' }
```

when i dump it into JSON format, i would like for it to print out as

```
{ 'name': 'Smith', 'department': 'HR', 'country': 'us', 'phone': '1234567890'}
```

Comment: You need to give an example of your dictionary inclusive the code that you are working on.

Comment: Your question is unclear. An ordered dictionary is ordered because it "remembers" the order the key/value pairs were added in. Since you're starting from a "normal" dictionary, there is no concept of ordering in your input data. You would have to sort the keys somehow before (or while) feeding the ordered dictionary (such as taking an ordered list of keys, as Sai does in their answer).

Comment: Sorry about that ... will add it now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could do something like the following ... you collect the keys in order in a list of String, traverse through the list and look up in the dictionary, and create an ordered dictionary

```
def makeOrderedDict(dictToOrder, keyOrderList):
    tupleList = []
    for key in keyOrderList:
        tupleList.append((key, dictToOrder[key]))
    return OrderedDict(tupleList)
```

Comment: I'd suggest you take a look at your code and see if you can create an OrderedDict in the first place.

Comment: ... or if you even really need an OrderedDict.

Answer (score 0):

Sort your dict items and create an `OrderedDict` from the sorted elements making sure to pass `reverse=True` to sort from highest to lowest:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

order = ("name","department","country","phone")
employee = { 'phone': '1234567890', 'department': 'HR', 'country': 'us', 'name': 'Smith' }
od = OrderedDict((k, employee[k]) for k  in order)
```

But if you dump to a json file and load again the order will **not** be maintained and you will **not** get an OrderedDict back, when you dump it will  look like:

```
 {"name": "Smith", "department": "HR", "country": "us", "phone": "1234567890"}
```

But loading will will not be in the same order because normal dicts have no order like below:

```
{'phone': '1234567890', 'name': 'Smith', 'country': 'us', 'department': 'HR'}
```

If you are trying to just store the dicts to use again and want to maintain order you can pickle:

```
import pickle

with open("foo.pkl","wb") as f:
   pickle.dump(od,f)

with open("foo.pkl","rb") as f:
   d = pickle.load(f)
   print(d)
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear in the question ... I need the key-value pairs in a certain order that is pre-determined and not necessarily sorted. I edited my question to, hopefully, reduce the ambiguity